# Creating a bash associative array from a file containing colon delimiter

Tags: bash

I have a file called countries.txt

```
cat countries.txt
Germany:berlin
Japan:tokyo
usa:washington
canada:ottawa
uk:london

file='countries.txt'
readarray -t countries < "$file"

for i in "${!countries[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${filenames[$i]}"
done

key  : 0                   
value: Germany:berlin   
key  : 1                   
value: Japan:tokyo   
key  : 2                   
value: usa:washington    
key  : 3                   
value: canada:ottawa  
key  : 4                   
value: uk:london
```

my bash version is 4.1.2

The output i was expecting to see is the Key that is the countries and the values that is their capitals

After help from Inian below and using IFS=: i get some weird answer like this

```
declare -A countries
file='countries.txt'

while IFS=: read -r key value; do
    countries["$key"]="$value"
done < "$file"

for cap in "${!countries[@]}"; do
    echo "$cap" "${countries[$cap]}"
done

Japan:tokyo      
uk london        
usa:washington   
canada:ottawa    
Germany berlin   
canada ottawa    
Germany:berlin   
0 countries.txt  
uk:london        
usa washington   
Japan tokyo
```

Comment: `${filenames[$i]}` ? Do you mean `${countries[$i]}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mapfile`/`readarray` built-ins in `bash` are known to create *only* indexed arrays. Since you are not providing any de-limiter to split the input file content, the command just creates one entry in the array for each of the input lines present.

If you are looking to create an associative array with with the values before `:` to be used as keys, you need a `while` loop parsing each line splitting it on `:` and declare the array to be used as associative explicitly. Note that associative arrays are available from versions greater than 4 only.

```
# declares an explicit associative array
declare -A countries

while IFS=: read -r key value; do
    countries["$key"]="$value"
done < "$file"
```

now this array can be looped over the indices and elements can be printed as

```
for cap in "${!countries[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$cap" "${countries[$cap]}"
done
```

See [BashGuide/Arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for more detailed information on how to use various array types in `bash`.

Comment: Hi Thanks a ton for taking time out and looking at this i still have issue with the results

Comment: @jhon.smith: Your array is having stale values from your previous command. You need to do `unset countries; declare -A countries` or `countries=()` and run my command again

Comment: Hi Inian brilliant that is indeed the issue Thanks a ton.